# Pterodactyl Server Console Websocket Authorization

Tags: javascript, authentication, websocket, ws

I am trying to establish a websocket connection to my server running on the Pterodactyl Software.
But I don't know how to authorize myself to pterodactyl.

The docs say:

> **How to connect**
> Connect to the websocket address (in this example  "wss://pterodactyl.file.properties:8080/api/servers/1a7ce997-259b-452e-8b4e-cecc464142ca/ws")
> Send the token to the websocket like this: {"event":"auth","args":["eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6Ij..."]}
> Tokens last about 10-15 minutes, and the websocket will notify you once you need to send a new token with {"event":"token expiring"} and {"event":"token expired"}

And I tried that in my Code:

```js
const { WebSocket } = require('ws');
const ws = new WebSocket(`wss://example.com:8080/api/servers/myServerUUID/ws`);

ws.on(`open`, () => {
    ws.send({ event: "auth", args: [`mySuperSecretToken`] });
});

ws.on(`error`, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});

ws.on(`message`, data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

But it always gives me this error:

```
Error: Unexpected server response: 403
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\RappyTV\Documents\Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:886:7)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (node:_http_client:631:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:128:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:494:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fix:**
I should have put the pterodactyl origin in an object as a second argument in the `WebSocket` constructor:

```js
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://example.com:8080/api/servers/myServerUUID/ws', { origin: 'https://example.com' });
```

And I forgot to stringify the message to the WebSocket:

```js
ws.on(`open`, () => {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({ event: "auth", args: [`mySuperSecretToken`] }));
});
```